# "As knows all the tiptop young fellas?"— Is it correct?

Tags: as

In old movie 'Lady Chatterley', the actor says "as knows all the tiptop young fellas?".

Is 'as knows all the tiptop young fellas' grammatically correct? Is it like old English or some dialects?

If not, what is the correct version?

---

**Movie Script**

> Woman: I saw you once, washing.
>
> Woman: I thought you were beautiful.
>
> Man: Me?
>
> Woman: your body was beautiful. I 
>   wanted you.
>
> Man: My body, beautiful? To you? **As knows all the tiptop young fellas?**
>
> Woman: I don't mean handsome.
>
> Man: Handsome is as handsome does.

Answer (score 27):

Both answers given are completely wrong.

The subject is not "all the tiptop young fellas", but "you". "As" is a dialect version of the relative pronoun "who", or "that". The meaning is

> To you? Who knows all the tiptop young fellas?

Formally, the verb should still be "know", to agree with "you", and I think in formal speech of the time, anybody would have said

> You, who know ...

but in the dialect that uses "as", that sounds odd.

I think "as knows" can almost be treated as an idiom at the time.

Comment: +1. https://books.google.com/books?id=UB8TaTggBvQC&q=%22you+as+knows%22&dq=%22you+as+knows%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS74yPiMrUAhUBcj4KHfHKAggQ6AEIKDAA

Comment: +1 The script's punctuation is odd—when I've seen this usage written down, there's usually no punctuation between "you" and "as" (like in @Tᴚoɯɐuo's citation).

Comment: +1 I might posit the that there is an elided "someone" to explain the know/knows discrepency: *To you? [Someone] who **knows**...*

Comment: You may want to rephrase your first sentence to explain what the wrong interpretation was more explicitly. Some answers have been edited, and now there are 3 of them.

Comment: The sentence structure is quite awkward.  It's equally possible to parse it as "My body is beautiful, to you?  As all the tiptop young fellas know it is?", implying that the speaker (somewhat boastfully) considers it common knowledge that he has a nice body and is merely surprised the the woman thinks so too.  I see little to bias against such an interpretation, apart from the context of a (presumably straight) man talking to a straight woman, and the unlikelihood that a straight man would know or want to boast about what other men think of his body.

Comment: @aroth In the context I don't think it's possible to parse it the way you imply. The preceding sentence "To you?" pretty much precludes it. Also if you were to parse it the way you suggest the "knows" would actually need to be "know".

Comment: @DRF - The "To you?" could associate with either sentence, insofar as that fragment produces a valid result when appended to the preceding or prepended to the following sentence.  A clear way to indicate that it definitely goes with the following sentence would have been to make the second '?' a comma instead, as in 'To you, as ...'.  And as the answer points out, even with "you" the "knows" should technically be "know".

Comment: @aroth The you isn't the subject in my opinion. Rather there is an elided someone as Sabrr points out. So really it's "To you? As [someone who] knows all the tiptop young fellas?" Of course there is the fact that part of the reason he talks like this is to point to the large class difference thua there might be aome exageration.

Comment: I don't accept the "As someone who knows" explanation. In dialect speech "as" is fully normal as a relative pronoun., usually with the antecedent explicit. It's only because it's tagged on to the sentence "To you?" that there is any doubt that "you" is the subject.

Answer (score 4):

After a little research I have to admit I wasn't right the first time. This is indeed a dialect version of "**who/that**".

> - **Woman**: Your body was beautiful. I wanted you.
> - **Man**: My body, beautiful? To you? As knows all the tiptop young fellas?

The man is actually saying this:

- You think my body is beautiful? To you, who knows all the tiptop young fellas?

"**As**" is referring to the woman - singular so the verb "**knows**" is correct here.

More examples of such usage:

[Fatal Elixir by William L. DeAndrea](https://books.google.ru/books?id=jC42O4l4vSoC&pg=PT278&lpg=PT278&dq=%22somebody%20as%20knows%22&source=bl&ots=hNA8eb14PL&sig=kKzWkqYnPS8vC64ezraQRoxR0SU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW55j1kMrUAhXiB5oKHeX4CIQQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22somebody%20as%20knows%22&f=false)
[Sixpenny Girl by Meg Hutchinson](https://books.google.ru/books?id=gzqpmJbftJEC&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=%22somebody%20as%20knows%22&source=bl&ots=E_av_vBMPL&sig=sKEdNliWukxWzvctUPgcnozBDKs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW55j1kMrUAhXiB5oKHeX4CIQQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=%22somebody%20as%20knows%22&f=false)
[The Wheelwright's Shop by George Sturt](https://books.google.ru/books?id=nNwE4oiT1HIC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%22somebody%20as%20knows%22&source=bl&ots=LCAG3DPMcg&sig=l00hCCcheXQdy7wWZjbIzYepl6U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW55j1kMrUAhXiB5oKHeX4CIQQ6AEINjAG#v=onepage&q=%22somebody%20as%20knows%22&f=false)
[The Dramatic Works of William Shakspeare: Accurately Printed from the Text by William Shakespeare, Samuel Johnson, George Steevens, Isaac Reed](https://books.google.ru/books?id=XiI3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA776&dq=%22we%20as%20know%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv2b3xkcrUAhWkB5oKHTalDG4Q6AEITjAI#v=onepage&q=%22we%20as%20know%22&f=false)

Comment: What's with the down-votes? I've edited my answer!

Comment: I think the downvotes relate to the issue of number agreement of the verb *You know* is standard (you, who know) but here the third person is being used with the second person, another dialect/sociolect feature. https://books.google.com/books?id=lVg2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA211&dq=%22you+as+was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9kJS-tMzUAhXBaD4KHfqBC18Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22you%20as%20was%22&f=false  "You're the old woman...as **was** that disgraceful intosticated [sic]...." or   "I can swear, mum, as you **was** as sober as a judge..."

Comment: Here's another example of **as** :)  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280095/if-cow-beef-pig-pork-and-deer-venison-then-where-is-the-word-for-human/280096#280096

Comment: You have my upvote for finding additional examples, which makes it easier to extrapolate beyond this one specific sentence.

Answer (score -2):

No.  It's simply English slang.  "As knows" would properly be written "Who knows", and "tiptop" should be hyphenated "tip-top".

Comment: -1 for the unsubstantiated claim that _tiptop_ "should be hyphenated". I can link to over a [dozen dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=tiptop&ls=a) that disagree with you.